# Firebase Crash - batch upload not works anymore

Tags: ios, batch-file, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-crash-reporting

First of all, I'm using firebase crashreporting since February. Because of bitcode (for the prod versions), I need to download DSYMs and upload from terminal. It's all ok, but today, I faced that the script that I used not working anymore. I did NOT changed anything, nor in the service account files, nor in the script.

I'm getting a warning, that my service account file is not like a service account file

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload /Project/ServiceAccount.json F3B……..5272
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload:83: warning: The first argument does not look like a service account file.
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload:127: warning: Running extract-keys on desktop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this script previously, which not worked today:

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload /ProjectName/Firebase_Crash.json B5CF...8A
```

And the working one...:

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload ./ProjectName/Firebase_Crash.json B5CF...8A
```

This one also works:

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload -i ./ProjectName/Info.plist -p ./ProjectName/GoogleService-Info.plist ./ProjectName/Firebase_Crash.json B5CF...8A
```